# Setting image in input element background not working

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to set an image within an input element but the image is not showing.

html:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input class="form-control ccnumber" type="text" id="creditCardNo" 
          formControlName="creditCardNo">
    </div>
```

css:

```
.ccnumber {
    background-image: url("creditcard.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your path to the image. Your code is working fine. Check your network to see why it isn't loaded.

```css
.ccnumber {
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control ccnumber" type="text" id="creditCardNo" 
         formControlName="creditCardNo">
</div>
```

Comment: When I checked the console, the css shows the following instead of the css: background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARgAAAC0CAMAAAB4+cOfAAABHVBMV…3A/iv3Sr5nyLbT8m6aWBLDh2HLkx4YnrX6hzJWxSAZ/wXluLl3+g88CQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); Would you know why that is?

Comment: It gets the image as byte array